# Copy Row To Another Sheet Based On Cell Value In Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm Trying it:

```
 =FILTER('Orginal'!A:D, 'Orginal'!D:D="Complete")
```

Screens:

[image]

[image]

And i have Error. "formula analysis error"

[image]

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a syntax error here:

[image]

Please use the following formula:

`=FILTER('Orginal'!A2:D, 'Orginal'!D2:D="Complete")`

[image]

### update after finding solution

It turns out the solution had to do with the spreadsheet location.

The location of the spreadsheet can determine if the formulas have either a `comma` or a `semicolon`, as well as the format of the dates. To change your location of the spreadsheet, you can do it in:

`file => spreadsheet settings => locale` and change the locale there.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah bad screen.. but i found it... it was problem with this:

It shoud be :

```
=FILTER(Orginal!A:D;Orginal!D:D="Complete")
```

i changed "," to ";"

Comment: Then it has to do with the location of the spreadsheet you are in. The conventions (and formulas) change between locations. Some use the comma, some use the semicolon, and usually the date type also changes, you can see that by going to `file => spreadsheet settings => locale`

Comment: will edit my answer as well as it can help others with it