# How to call a custom function with multiple arguments in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a little problem. I made a custom function for my google spreadsheet but when i try to call i in a cell in my document it just gives me "#ERROR!". Im guessing this is happening because im trying to pass in 2 arguments into the function but for some reason it doesn't like that. Does anyone know why this doesn't work and how i could fix it?

```
function Test(val, sub) 
{
  return val - sub;
}
```

Cell input `=Test(77, 5)` returns "#ERROR!"

Comment: Try `=test(77;5)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296761 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314993 ?

Comment: "=test(77;5)" seems to have sovled the problem, but is it possible to change some settings so i could use comma instead of semicolon?

Comment: I've closed your question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64315058/ It shows how to change your locale. Preferably United States should do the trick.

Comment: Also, Consider accepting the answer below if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your usage and function, it should work.

I confirmed it by copying your function and testing it.

[image: testing]

[image: function showing next to debug]

**How to correct an #ERROR! error?**

> Carefully check your formula for accuracy.

Most `#ERROR` errors are caused by typos on the call of the function or on your actual function itself so you might have to check that.

You can try refreshing the sheet. It sometimes needs a refresh when your function was recently modified.

If it still doesn't work, kindly show the error the cell is showing with the formula. Just hover your pointer over the `#ERROR` cell and take a screen shot which should be like this:

[image: error]

- By doing this, it will tell us what caused the error. (In this case, I modified the function to induce an `#ERROR`, changing `val` to `val2`)

**EDIT:**

- As per TheMaster mentioned in the comment, it is caused by the delimiter <kbd>,</kbd>. And you just confirmed you are from Europe on a comment below, thus this actually applies to you.

**Locations using decimal commas:**

> For locations using commas to denote decimal separators (most European countries), the syntax will follow this structure:

> Decimals will be denoted by a comma
> Arguments in formulas separated by a semi-colon

Thus your function reads `77,5` as Test(77.5, ) which results into #NUM!

Use <kbd>;</kbd> instead.

`=Test(77;5)`

**Reference:**

- [#ERROR](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/formula-parse-error/#errorError)
- [Locations using decimal commas](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)

Comment: I mimicked what you did on the picture but when i use "=Test(77,5)" it doesn't give me 72, instead it gives me #NUM! At first it said #ERROR! now it only says #NUM! and when i hover over it says "result is not a number".

Comment: can you share a sample of your sheet @ExeQ?

Comment: @NaziA I'm pretty sure OP uses `,` as decimal separator. `=test(77, 5)` caused `#ERROR` as it is  the same as `77. 5` a syntax error due to the space. `#NUM` now because now it is `=test(77,5)`(space removed) => interpreted as ``=test(77.5, undefined)`` which returns `NaN` => `#NUM`

Comment: I see, I am currently editing the answer to include your findings, just found out about it. OP may be from a european country thus OP encounters this issue. Thanks @TheMaster

Comment: Yeah, im from a european country is that most likely why i get this problem? Also here is a link to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FGyCeUvCylqiQJRR0RUhq59GlXqeP1RARQueXSUYet0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have edited the answer as per TheMaster 's findings. kindly see the updated answer @ExeQ

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster for that wonderful insight.

Comment: Related meta: [Why should I include screenshots instead of a Google sheets link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/)